# How can I paint kitchen cabinet hinges?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, hinges

We have old, ugly kitchen cabinet hinges.  I've read conflicting opinions online as to whether spray painting them is a good idea.  How would you do it if you were going to go for it?

Comment: Are there budget constraints?  Powder coating would be my first choice (given unlimited resources).

Comment: Yes, or we would just buy new hinges.  Can powder coating be done at home or just by a professional?

Comment: Powdercoating is generally not something you DIY. The technique is to first airbrush the powdercoating solution (a dry powder, hence the term) onto the piece to be coated, usually with a static charge to attract the particles, and then bake the piece at high heat (more than your standard oven can provide; you basically need a kiln) to melt and cure the coating into a tough shell. Unless your needs require a truly custom job, I'd just get new hinges rather than go through this.

Comment: what material are the hinges?  if they are steel, then i would go with spraying (which also means that you could probably replace them at the same cost of a tin of paint)... Brass - i would not spray, you may consider an acid was, or stainless?

Answer (score 7):

Just to stop the ugliness, I would just get a can of Rust-Oleum gloss enamel (black, white, whatever), then remove the hinges from the cabinets.

Clean them thoroughly, and if there's any existing lacquer or hardcoat, try roughing them up with a bit of steel wool. If you can completely disassemble each hinge, that would be ideal; otherwise, work a small amount of silicone lube or grease into the action, to help keep the paint out of the hinge itself (keep the outer surfaces clean, though).

Then, simply give them a couple good coats of the enamel spray; each coat should cover well, but don't go too thick or you'll get runs, drips, etc, as well as having paint over the tops of the moving parts (which will then crack the first time you move the hinge). Let dry, flip and repeat. When both sides are done, reassemble and reinstall the hinges. The enamel should cure into a nice hard shell that should last you until you can spend the money to replace the hardware, or redo the whole kitchen.

Comment: yep. just what I would do, or maybe buy new hinges.  lol

Comment: Yeah, if I had the scratch I'd just get new hinges. That can add up over a full kitchen though, so this is the cheaper but more labor-intensive (translated: DIY) method.

Answer (score -1):

No matter how light you coat or what paint you use, it does not work.  Hinges pull off spray paint.

Comment: This isn't an answer - it's more suited as a comment on an answer suggesting the use of spray paint.